# What is "this" in jquery boolean toggle?

Tags: this, jquery

I was wondering what is the "this" in the jquery boolean toggle function. I ran a few tests when calling the toggle on a list of jQuery elements, and It's not `null` or `underfined`, it's not `window`, it's not a jQuery object or a dom element.

Any ideas?

Edit: Say this is my HTML

```
<div x="a">some div</div>
<div x="b">some div</div>
```

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
$('div').toggle(this.attributes['x'].value == 'a');
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are talking about..

Comment: In the implementation of toggle? In the arguments? In the scope of a function given as argument?

Comment: When you are talking about "jQuery boolean toggle function", what are you talking about exactly? There are 4 overloads of toggle. The one with the boolean argument does not have a function as an argument.

Comment: No it's not `body`! Careful, your code has a lot of misconceptions!

Comment: I have also provided you with a solution, in case you happen to come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which toggle function are you talking about, but I'm assuming it's one where there is some sort of a callback function, so that the question would make sense.

There are 3 overloads in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which is applicable:

> `.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

and

> `.toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

and also

> `.toggle( options )`

as in the `options` there are a few callback functions.

If you call any of them in a jQuery list, for example:

```
$('ul li').toggle(400, function() {});
```

It basically calls toggle on every element of the list, and the callback function will also be called on every element.

In every callback function `this` is one of the DOM elements the toggle is called on. In the above example it would be a `HTMLLIElement`.

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkHsy/) for you proving this.

If your question was something else please clarify it.

---

**EDIT**:

Seeing your comment under the accepted answer you seem to have a **huge misconception**!

your code is:

```
$('div').toggle(this == body);
```

In this syntax `this` comes from the CONTEXT.

Your fiddle is set to the `onLoad` event, so it will be the `window` object.

If you write it in the [jQuery ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) callback function (setting the jsfiddle setting to onDomready) it will be the `document` object.

This has nothing to do with the toggle function. In every C-like language calling a function with arguments is something like:

```
myFunction(arg1, arg2);
```

The values of `arg1` and `arg2` will be depend on the context where you call the function. You know: what is `arg1` and `arg2` at the given moment (at the moment you decide to call the function).

In JavaScript `this` is always the object that the current function you are in is called on.

Also in your fiddle `body` is undefined! There is no variable called `body` there, so calling `$('div').toggle(this == body);` will throw a `ReferenceError`.

---

**EDIT2**:

What you want to do is easy:

Instead of:

```
 $('div').toggle(this.attributes['x'].value == 'a');
```

Write:

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var attrx = $this.attr('x');
    $this.toggle(attrx == 'a');
});
```

In the callback function of [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `this` is the current DOM element you are iterating over.

---

**EDIT3**:

Replying to your first comment on this answer:

Your question does not make sense in it's own. I have tried to explain it in my first edit, it seems I have failed. I think you are confused by the jQuery syntax, or I don't know. Let me try to explain it again:

Any jQuery function (like `.toggle()`) is just a simple function at the end. It is just a function of the jQuery collection object. So these 2 lines work similarly:

```
console.log(this.attributes['x'].value == 'a');
$('div').toggle(this.attributes['x'].value == 'a');
```

- First, the expression `this.attributes['x'].value == 'a'` is evaluated. It will result in `true` or `false`.
- Then the function will be called with either true or false.

This will result in the same as the 2 lines above:

```
var preCalculate = this.attributes['x'].value == 'a';
console.log(preCalculate);
$('div').toggle(preCalculate);
```

I have moved out `this` from the `.toggle()` function yet it is the same. `this` is completely independent of the `.toggle()` function!

In JavaScript, the `this` keyword comes from the context:

- If it is the **Global context** (you are not in a function), the value of `this` will be the same as `window` (if you use JavaScript in the browser of course).
- If it is a **Function context** (you are in a function), the value of `this` will be the object the function is called on!

What is the object it is called on?

For example if you write:

```
car.honk();
```

You are calling the `.honk()` function on the `car` object.

You might have made this object like this:

```
var car = {
    name: "Ford Model T",
    honk: function () {
        alert(this.name + " is currently honking");
    }
};
```

After that you can call:

```
car.honk(); // this alerts "Ford Model T is currently honking"
```

This is because you called `.honk()` on the `car` object. So inside the `.honk()` function `this` was evaluated as the `car` object.

Note that the `alert` had no influence over the value of `this`. When you write `alert(this.name + " is currently honking");`, the arguments of the function are evaluated **before** the function is called! In this case the only argument is `this.name + " is currently honking"` which will be evaluated as `"Ford Model T is currently honking"`. Than `alert` will be called as `alert("Ford Model T is currently honking");`.

Let's say you change your car like this:

```
var car = {
    name: "Ford Model T",
    honk: function () {
        $('div').toggle(this.attributes['x'].value == 'a');
    }
};
```

What will happen? It will throw an exception, because the `car` object has no property called `attributes`! `this` is still the `car` object.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks @SoonDead, that's eventually what I did. but I was curious as to why the first version did not work - what IS "this" in the toggle?

Comment: Or just check this: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: WOW, @SoonDead, thanks for all the effort - this was great!. You are right, I got confused due to the jQuery syntaxing, expecting the currently running dom element to be available.

Comment: It is only available if it's in a callback function (since it's an other function, the context changes). jQuery calls the callback on the currently selected objects. If you check the first part of my answer (before the edits) there is an example jsfiddle there, where the current DOM element is available in the callback. Or check EDIT2.

Answer (score 0):

generally this refers to current element in jquery eg

```
$('#abc').click(function(){ 
    $(this) // this means the current element same as $('#abc') 
})
```

Comment: This is so low quality you deserve a downvote. He did not ask "generally", and stated that it does not seem to be "a jQuery object or a dom element".

Comment: He is wrong,  "stated that it does not seem to be "a jQuery object or a dom element"" - so what? @SoonDead answered him correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information with your test scenario. I used a simple

```
$("body").toggle();
```

The exceprt form the soure code 1.9.1

```
toggle: function( state ) {
    var bool = typeof state === "boolean";

    return this.each(function() { //1
        if ( bool ? state : isHidden( this ) ) {//2
            jQuery( this ).show();//3
        } else {
            jQuery( this ).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

When using Chrome to step through the function, here is what I got

1 => The regular jQuery context as you would expect it, Chrome debugger inspector output:

```
0: body
context: document
length: 1
prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
selector: "body"
```

2 => The iterated, plain DOM element, body in this case
3 => The same as 2, but since it gets passed to jQuery, you convert it into a jQuery object and have all the methods available again.

Comment: thanks @DrColossos, I got [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYpSX/1/) to return true

Comment: @Yaelet: This fiddle returns (well not exactly returns) `Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined`. It definitely doesn't return `true`.